# Retuning the value instead of item on filter the object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

this is my method: I am trying to change the `item.checked` from `true` in to `false` and i need the same length of element returned. but getting different result.

```
const headerUpdate = this.tableSchema.headers.map((item) => {
   return (item.checked ?? (item.checked = false)) || item;
});
```

result:

`[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, true]`

last element became true instead of item with false value.

**Sample data added**

```
headers: [
        {
            title: 'Primary Admin User ID',
            label: 'adminUserName',
            sortable: true,
            dir: true,
            sortType: 'string',
            sortActive: true,
        },
        {
            title: 'Name',
            label: 'customerName',
            sortable: true,
            sortType: 'string',
            dir: false,
        },
        {
            title: 'Address',
            label: 'address',
            sortable: true,
            link: false,
            dir: false,
            sortType: 'string',
            disabled: true,
        },
        {
            title: 'Phone Number',
            label: 'phoneNum',
            sortable: true,
            link: false,
            dir: false,
            sortType: 'string',
            disabled: true,
        },
        {
            label: 'CheckBox',
            link: false,
            dir: false,
            sortType: 'string',
            disabled: true,
            checkBox: true,
            checked: false,
        },
    ],
```

Comment: @GuerricP that should return without any change

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in one line? You don't have implicit return here and already have a block for the callback. This code is so hard to read and doesn't have any upside

Comment: (item) => { item.checked = false; return item; }
But using map does not seem tp be a good approach here.

Comment: @adiga if this is not possible i will change

Comment: `.map((item) => (item.checked ??=false, item))` or `.map((item) => (item.checked = false, item))` based on your requirement.

Comment: So, you want to update `checked` property to `false`, only if the property exists in item?

Comment: I just reread the title. Why does the word "filter" appear in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to either mutate the array with a `forEach`, or `map` and return a whole new object in the callback, because right now you have a kind of hybrid code between the two.

```
const headerUpdate = this.tableSchema.headers.map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  ...item.checked === undefined ? undefined : { checked: false },
}));
```

Comment: Yes, or `=> Object.assign(item, { checked: false })`

Comment: @danh that mutates `item`

Comment: @adiga - it does indeed, which appears to be the OP's intent

Comment: @Gurric P , this problem is it's adding a attribute as `checked: false ` to all items. it should alter only where the attribute `checked` exist

Comment: @3gwebtrain I've updated with what you actually need